# VF page works in preview (only in lightning), but doesn't work anywhere else

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html

```
     <apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="atRisk" title=" Risk"  doctype="html-5.0">
    <apex:messages />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://tableaureporting.domaintest.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js"></script> 


        <script type="text/javascript">
       function checkAll(cb)
{
    var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
            inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
    }
}         

               var containerDiv = document.getElementById("viz");
               var trustedurl ="{!rootURL+'/t/Sales_Ops/views/Analysis/Analysis?:render=false'}";
                var options = {
                hideTabs: false,
                toolbarPosition: tableauSoftware.ToolbarPosition.TOP,
                width: '1250px',
                height:'800px',
                    // ACCT_EXEC: '0003800165'

                };

                viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(containerDiv, trustedurl, options);
                viz.addEventListener('marksselection', onMarksSelection);  



                function listenToMarksSelection() { 
           viz.addEventListener(tableauSoftware.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, onMarksSelection);
          }

    function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) { 
       return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(reportSelectedMarks);
    }
         function reportSelectedMarks(marks) {
        if (marks == null || marks == '')
        {

        }

        for (var markIndex = 0; markIndex < marks.length; markIndex++) {
                var pairs = marks[markIndex].getPairs();

            var customerName_v = "";
            var customerNum_v = "";

                for (var pairIndex = 0; pairIndex < pairs.length; pairIndex++) {
                    var pair = pairs[pairIndex];

                if (pair.fieldName == "Cust Code")
                {
                    customerNum_v = pair.formattedValue;
                    //customerNumJS(customerNum_v); 
                    //customerNum_v = pair.formattedValue;
                }
                else if (pair.fieldName == "Customer")
                {
                    customerName_v = pair.formattedValue; 
                    //customerJS(customerName_v);


                }
                 getInfoJS(customerNum_v, customerName_v);

                     console.log(' custname  ' + customerNum_v + customerName_v);
                }

                html += "</ul>";
              }


      }

   </script>




 <div id="viz"></div>



    </apex:page>
```

So when in lightning i go to the VF page hit preview and it opens in a new screen (without any sfdc UI) and it works. The second i imbed it in any page or try to preview it in classic it only loads the text on the markDetails section the "Information about selected markers displays huur".

Doesn't work in classic at all in preview or embedded, doesn't work on a lightning app either.

Comment: Did you check your Developer Console for any JS errors?

Comment: @ElieNassif I did, it's some restriction related to SFDC......sadface. I ended up getting it working but had to do some changes to how it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved see the code above for the fixed version to this question